# Question about "in such a way as would make them seem magical and occult"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, conjunctions, sentence-structure

I have a question about the sentence "liked to do things in such a way as would make them seem magical and occult" from the novel "Waterland" that was written by Graham Swift. Link [here](http://www.fiction2.com/waterland-online-graham-swift?page=0,0).

Below is the sentence in which I have a question.

> And my father, who was a superstitious man, liked to do things in such a way as would make them seem magical and occult.

I know from the Oxford Dictionaries that "such ... as ..." above means

> [such](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/such)
>
> 2. Of the type about to be mentioned

But I don't know which meaning of the word "of" is used in this explanation. I am not very clear about "of the type" in the explanation.

Is the word "as" a conjunction in the sentence "in such a way as would make them seem magical and occult"?

Which meaning of the word "as" is used in the sentence "in such a way as would make them seem magical and occult"?

Comment: Do you know what a _preposition_ is in English?

Comment: @P.E.Dant    "at" is a preposition.

Comment: And what about "of?"

Comment: Is the word "of" a preposition in "Of the type about to be mentioned"? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In a way that would make them seem magical

Comment: It is better for _you_ if we show you how to answer your own questions! Here, you can answer your own question if you understand what _**of**_ means in English. It's a preposition, and it always signifies something about possession. Read the definitions and examples [here.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/of?s=t) Next, read [this](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/type?s=ts) defintion of _type._ Then look at your questions about "of." Do you see now what "of the type" means?

Comment: The explanations from Dictionary.com are difficult for me. I read the explanations from Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary. http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/of    Does the word "of" mean "belong to" in "Of the type about to be mentioned"?     http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/type   Does the word "type" mean "a particular kind or group of things or people"?

Comment: Good for you for looking up "such as"!  We like to see people doing research!  But the original sentence doesn't say "such as", which is why looking it up didn't help you.  Try looking up the words "such", "a way" and "as" separately.  I think [the definition of "as" that you want is "4.
in the manner (directed, agreed, promised, etc.)"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as)

Answer (score 1):

He liked to do things **in such a way as** would make them seem magical.

You can replace **"in such a way as"** in the above sentence with:

He liked to do things **in a way that** would make them seem magical.

"in such a way as" would mean: **in this particular way that**...

Comment: Is the clause "as would make them seem magical and occult" an attributive clause that modifies "a way" in the sentence "liked to do things in such a way as would make them seem magical and occult"?

Comment: I wouldn't say it modifies "a way". Here is a link that could probably help you further: http://goo.gl/nJECzM

Comment: What does the clause "as would make them seem magical and occult" modify in the sentence "liked to do things in such a way as would make them seem magical and occult"?  Thank you so much for your help.